# Making font larger in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, fonts

I'm trying to make my font size larger while working in VSCode. I go to the view tab, choose appearances, then "zoom in", but it keeps giving me this error message: "Unable to write into user settings. Please open the user settings to correct errors/warnings in it and try again." I clicked on the "Open Settings" button and it took me to {}settings.json, but I have no idea what errors to look for or what needs to be corrected. I should have said that I'm working on an iMac.  Does anyone know what needs to be changed or inserted? Here are the json settings:

```
"workbench.activityBar.visible": true,
"workbench.sideBar.location": "right",
"terminal.integrated.shell.osx": "/bin/bash",
"python.terminal.executeInFileDir": true,
"[python]": {

},
"editor.suggestSelection": "first",

"vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": 
"automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
"java.semanticHighlighting.enabled": true,
"workbench.editorAssociations": [
    {
        "viewType": "jupyter.notebook.ipynb",
        "filenamePattern": "*.ipynb"
    }
],
"python.languageServer": "Microsoft",
"extensions.ignoreRecommendations": true,
"files.defaultLanguage": "python",
```

Comment: There might be syntax errors in your `settings.json`. Can you copy and paste your `settings.json` file here? You can open that file by opening the command palette (`Ctrl + Shift + P`) and run `Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)`

Comment: Thank you so much for responding. I edited the post to include the code I got by following your instructions.

Comment: Thanks for the update! Did you wrap all these settings with a curly brace? (`{ }`) The JSON file must begin with a `{` brace and end with a `}` brace